# Finding climate tabular data on specific area

Tags: google-earth-engine, data

I'm new to this sector and I would like to find a sort of tabular dataset regarding climate information (weekly/daily: precipitation, humidity, windy, and so on) for a specific area of interest (in my case north Italy). I'm looking on the Google Earth Engine but it seems there is only an "images" dataset.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: You can transform those images into tabular data in GEE, using for example, `reduceRegion` or similar methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GEE does have a quite a few datasets involving climate variables. I'm listing a few datasets that may be of interest to you on there:

- ERA5 - ECMWF Climate Reanalysis
- Reprocessed GLDAS-2.0: Global Land Data Assimilation System
- CFSR: Climate Forecast System Reanalysis

Beyond these remote sensing datasets, you'd probably have to look at getting monitor data directly and interpolating if the desired locations do not match your location of interest.